# Collection view inside JSQ message bubble chat

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using IOS, firebase, and JSQ Messaging. I want to display a collective view inside the JSQ Message bubble chat in both incoming and outcoming. The scenario is the following:

If the message type was: "Collection", then a collection view inside the jsq message bubble chat must show the icon image of sent id's (previously imbedded inside the app).

If the message type was: "text", then the JSQ message bubble chat will show the message normally.

Any ideas of how to implement a collection view inside a JSQ message bubble chat?